# Dynamically setting passwordMask in Titanium

Tags: passwords, titanium, titanium-alloy

Since Titanium doesn't allow you to manually change the hintText colour of a textfield, I have to set hintText manually. Because of this, I have to dynamically change the passwordMask setting on one of fields I'm using.

However, I'm getting weird behaviour and I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong, or if it's a bug in Titanium.

So, here's my markup:

```
<TextField id="password" onFocus="passwordFocusEvent" onReturn="passwordReturnEvent" onBlur="passwordBlurEvent" value="password"></TextField>
```

And some of my controller code:

```
function passwordFocusEvent(e) {
    slideViewUp();
    if (e.value === 'password') {
        e.source.setPasswordMask(true);
        e.source.value = '';
    }
}

function passwordBlurEvent(e) {
    if (!e.value) {
        e.source.setPasswordMask(false);
        e.source.value = 'password';
    }
}

function passwordReturnEvent(e) {
    slideViewDown();
    passwordBlurEvent(e);
}
```

What happens is bizarre. When I focus on the password field, it remains plain text. I enter some text, then click off to another field, stays as plain text.

I click back to the password field, it's STILL plain text.

Now here's the weirdness. Up to this point, I would just assume it's not working. However, when I click off this second time, the passwordMask is set.

Major WTF.

I even tried targeting the field directly using `$.password.passwordMask = true;` but same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cant do this. [According to the docs on Ti.UI.TextField](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-passwordMask) in the fine print;

> Note: on iOS, passwordMask must be specified when this text field is created.

Its not all bad news though, there are a couple ways you can approach this, one option is to make the password mask yourself, by listening to the `change` event:

```
var theStoredPassword = '';
$.password.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var newpass = e.source.value; 

    if(newpass.length < theStoredPassword.length) {
        // Character deleted from end
        theStoredPassword = theStoredPassword.substring(0, theStoredPassword.length-1);
    } else {
        // Character added to end
        theStoredPassword += newpass.substring(newpass.length-1);
    }
    // Mask the text with unicode ● BLACK CIRCLE, 25CF
    $.password.value = new Array(newpass.length + 1).join('●');
});
```

Another option, would be to have *two* text fields and swap them out whenever the user focuses the password field, the top one would have the custom hinttext, the bottom one would be passwordMasked. In fact thats probably way easier than what I just coded up. :-)

Comment: It's so weird that setPaswordMask is even available if it won't work... maybe it works in Android?

Comment: I think it works on android, mobileweb, and tizen, just no iOS :-(

Comment: Weird... thanks to your answer, I came up with a simple solution: I just use a label inside the text field and hide/show it as needed!